# Access the ressource of the View from the viewmodel WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf

I have a View with a DataTemplate

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TrackChangeTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

and i want in the View :

```
 SimpleLink link = new SimpleLink();
    link.Detail = (DataTemplate)Resources["TrackChangeTemplate"];
    link.DetailCount = 1;
    link.CreateDocument(true);
```

However i can't access the Resouces :
(DataTemplate)Resources["TrackChangeTemplate"]; Resources is not known

John

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
try 
{
  object resource = Application.Current.FindResource("TrackChangeTemplate");
}
catch (ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException ex) 
{
 ///stuff here to hande
}
```